# How to typeset stacked, unrelated equations?

Tags: equations

I fail to find a way to typeset a stack of unrelated equations. As an example, I would like to have these two unrelated equations one under the other: `ax+by+c=0` and `E=mc^2`.

I could go for `\begin{align}...\end{align}` but there is no particular reason to align them against something.

I tried to break them via `\\` in a `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` environment but this is not taken into account (the equations are concatenated in one line).

I tried `\begin{multiline}...\end{multiline}` and `\\` but it breaks the equations and justify them one to the left and one to the right.

I finally broke them into two `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` but they are too much spaced vertically.

**Is there a simple "multiline left justified" environment I could use?**

As a workaround, if there are no straightforward solutions I will probably go for `align`.

Comment: You have the `gather` environment:  each equation is centred.

Comment: @Bernard: thanks - this is what I will indeed use. Actually, after typing the whole question I found it in a suggestion (to which I directly redirected as a duplicate)